# How to use eval to force variable update

Tags: shell, unix, eval

I was reading the bash advanced scripting guide (if memory serves me right), and it said something to the extent that `eval` can be used to force variable updates.

So I tried this:

```
randomPath="/path/$var/here/"  # var is not defined at this point
echo $randomPath
/path//here/
var="is" # initially defining var
eval $randomPath
zsh: no such file or directory: /path//here/
```

I don't understand the error message, and I'm wondering if I'm using eval properly.

The output I was expecting is:

```
eval $randomPath
echo $randomPath
/path/is/here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$var` is already being substituted in `randomPath="/path/$var/here/"`, and because it is blank, `randomPath` is set to `/path//here`. You want to use single quotes to prevent the early substitution:

```
randomPath='/path/$var/here/'
```

The second problem is that `eval x` runs `x` as a command. What you want to do is return the newly evaluated variable as a string:

```
eval echo $randomPath
```

You can store it in a variable in the usual way:

```
randomPath=`eval echo $randomPath`
```